# Build task per ABI not working on Gradle plugin 3.0.1?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, gradlew

The following `build.gradle` works for Gradle Plugin v2.3.2 (but not 3.0.1), allowing to run `./gradlew assembleX86Release` at CLI:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    splits {

        // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
        abi {

            // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
            enable true

            // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
            // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.

            // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
            reset()

            // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
            include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "mips"

            // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk false
        }
    }
}

// Map for the version code that gives each ABI a value.
ext.abiCodes = ['armeabi-v7a':1, mips:2, x86:3]

import com.android.build.OutputFile

// For each APK output variant, override versionCode with a combination of
// ext.abiCodes * 1000 + variant.versionCode. In this example, variant.versionCode
// is equal to defaultConfig.versionCode. If you configure product flavors that
// define their own versionCode, variant.versionCode uses that value instead.
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    // Assigns a different version code for each output APK
    // other than the universal APK.
    variant.outputs.each { output ->

        // Stores the value of ext.abiCodes that is associated with the ABI for this variant.
        def baseAbiVersionCode =
                // Determines the ABI for this variant and returns the mapped value.
                project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))

        // Because abiCodes.get() returns null for ABIs that are not mapped by ext.abiCodes,
        // the following code does not override the version code for universal APKs.
        // However, because we want universal APKs to have the lowest version code,
        // this outcome is desirable.
        if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {

            // Assigns the new version code to versionCodeOverride, which changes the version code
            // for only the output APK, not for the variant itself. Skipping this step simply
            // causes Gradle to use the value of variant.versionCode for the APK.
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    baseAbiVersionCode * 1000 + variant.versionCode
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

At version 3.0.1, the following error is returned:

```
$ ./gradlew assembleX86Release
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'assemblex86Release' not found in root project 'MyApplication'.
Some candidates are: 'assembleRelease'.
```

however `./gradlew assembleRelease` is creating all split APKs.

Is any additional configuration required to build the APK per ABI or is this a Gradle plugging bug?

Comment: What happens when you use it? What are your symptoms? I pasted your `splits` into a test project, and it split just fine.

Comment: @CommonsWare Just added in the description. Basically I've created a new app and added the multiple APKs config described at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html

Comment: When you run `assembleRelease`, do you get your split APKs?

Comment: Yes, all of them! Only the build per ABI task is not working.

Comment: I never knew there were per-ABI tasks when using splits. If that is important to you, you could try switching to product flavors with `abiFilter`. Whether your results represent a bug or a dropped feature, I can't say.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example? I tried this modification, but it is not build a single APK per flavor https://gist.github.com/jpventura/4fe1aa0abbd38646f35c12e029e79e9c

Comment: With what you have in that gist, you should now have per-flavor `assemble` variants (e.g., `assembleArm7`), though you'll want to get rid of the `splits` closure. Leastways, when I paste your product flavors stuff into a project, I see `assembleArm7` in the Gradle tool's list of tasks in Android Studio.